# No database creation with 'db.create_all()' in Flask

Tags: python, flask, web

`db.create_all()` doesn't create database in flask, nothing happens.

I am following a tutorial on creating a website with Flask, and this code is meant to create a database:

```
with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

However, when i run my main.py file, the database is not created. Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
db=SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME="database.db"


def create_app():
    app=Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY']='coniferouslyfantastical'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views,url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth,url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User, Messages
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    return app
```

I do not receive any errors, its just that the database doesn't create.

Comment: How do you run `create_app()`?

Comment: in my main.py file, i have a line called app=create_app()